# Yocto Jethro: How to choose a Yocto Default Compiler? glibc failed at do_compile when use gcc 4.9

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

Because of old Das u-boot from HEAD branch that do not have gcc 5 yet, I am planning on using gcc 4.8 or 4.9 as a default compiler instead of 5.2.

GCC required virtual/libc glibc-2.22.  glibc-2.22 complied successfully with 5.2. Unfortunately, it failed at do_compile with the error: `ld: cannot find -lgcc` with gcc 4.8 and 4.9

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -marm  -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board-tcbootstrap   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -r -o /yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.22-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/elf/librtld.map.o '-Wl,-(' /yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.22-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/elf/dl-allobjs.os /yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.22-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/libc_pic.a -lgcc '-Wl,-)' -Wl,-Map,/yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.22-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/elf/librtld.mapT
/yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi.gcc-cross-initial-arm/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi.gcc-cross-initial-arm/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.2.0/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.22-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/elf/librtld.map] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory `/yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.22-r0/git/elf'
make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/yocto/hio-jethro/build-hio/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.22-r0/git'
make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
```

Am I looking at the right error?  and How do I add `-lgcc`?

**Edit:**
I have checked with Fido Branch and everything is working fine. I might just need replace gcc and glibc with Fido's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you tell it to use GCC 4?  The paths are still referencing 5.2.0, which suggests that you didn't change it correctly.  The correct way to change GCC version is to set GCCVERSION, ie `GCCVERSION="4.%"`.

Also u-boot in jethro supports gcc5 just fine, so why are you using an old release?

Comment: I have added 'PREFERRED_VERSION_gcc ?= "4.9%" and all its related to local.conf. I am using the old u-boot is because the one I am using is more than 2 years old and does not support gcc5.  Still need to update but do not have time yet. I do not know why it still calls 5.2 at some part though.

Comment: Could you add GCCVERSION = "4.9%" to you answer?  Thanks for helping.