# Yocto Morty 2.2 ld: cannot find -lgcc in glibc 2.24-r0

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, yocto

the glibc (libgcc.a) is well present in /usr/lib/ path.
I want to build a linux image core-image-minimal-dev with sdk and devtools.
It fails when linking the glibc (only here so far, about 50% of all tasks went smoothly)

How do i need to set the path and libraries (in local.conf)? to find -lgcc or how do i configure correctly? Thank you. Here is the error message:

```
| x86_64-poky-linux-gcc  -m64 -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 -mfpmath=sse -msse4.2 --sysroot=/home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/sysroots/kontron-kbox-a103-tcbootstrap   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -r -o /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/libc_pic.os \
|  -Wl,-d -Wl,--whole-archive /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/libc_pic.a -o /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/libc_pic.os
| x86_64-poky-linux-gcc  -m64 -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 -mfpmath=sse -msse4.2 --sysroot=/home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/sysroots/kontron-kbox-a103-tcbootstrap   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -r -o /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/elf/librtld.map.o '-Wl,-(' /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/elf/dl-allobjs.os /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/libc_pic.a -lgcc '-Wl,-)' -Wl,-Map,/home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/elf/librtld.mapT
| /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/x86_64-poky-linux.gcc-cross-initial-x86_64/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/6.2.0/ld: cannot find -lgcc
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| Makefile:349: recipe for target '/home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/elf/librtld.map' failed
| make[2]: *** [/home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/build-x86_64-poky-linux/elf/librtld.map] Error 1
| make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/git/elf'
| Makefile:234: recipe for target 'elf/subdir_lib' failed
| make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/git'
| Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/developer/yocto/Poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/glibc/2.24-r0/temp/log.do_compile.106361)
ERROR: Task (/home/developer/yocto/Poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.24.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1258 tasks of which 1106 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/developer/yocto/Poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.24.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Any other outputs or files needed to help? BR Florian

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the default GCC compiler?
Take a look at this file: [tcmode-default.inc](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/conf/distro/include/tcmode-default.inc?h=morty)
It is the file that set the default compiler target.

I also had similar problem before that I could not find -lgcc. [Yocto Jethro: How to choose a Yocto Default Compiler? glibc failed at do_compile when use gcc 4.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704776/yocto-jethro-how-to-choose-a-yocto-default-compiler-glibc-failed-at-do-compile)